# Twilio Whatsapp chatbot multiuser issue

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, chatbot, whatsapp

I am building a chatbot using Twilio and Nodejs, and the conversation flow is going well, but when I test it by multiple users it get clossapsed, the conversation of one user disrupts the flow of another user.

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { MessagingResponse } = require('twilio').twiml;
const User = require('./models/messageSchema')

const mongooseURI = 'mongodb+srv://rishavjhavinayan:RVtzjjTUSf11MB98@cluster0.ct9hcdc.mongodb.net/'

mongoose.connect(mongooseURI);
const db = mongoose.connection;


router.use(session({
    secret: 'secret_key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));


const products = [
    { name: "Product 1", description: "Description of Product 1" },
    { name: "Product 2", description: "Description of Product 2" },
    { name: "Product 3", description: "Description of Product 3" },
    { name: "Product 4", description: "Description of Product 4" }
];

let isViewingProducts = false;
let isReportingIssue = false; // Flag to track if user is reporting an issue
let currentUser = null; // Track current user
let userData = {}; // Object to store user data during issue reporting


const showProducts = () => {

    let response = "---- Available Products ----\n\n";
    products.forEach((product, index) => {
        response += `${index + 1}. ${product.name}\n`;
    });
    isViewingProducts = true;
    return response;

}

const getProductDetails = (index) => {
    // Define your products here
    const products = [
        { name: "Product 1", description: "Description of Product 1" },
        { name: "Product 2", description: "Description of Product 2" },
        { name: "Product 3", description: "Description of Product 3" },
        { name: "Product 4", description: "Description of Product 4" }
    ];

    // Check if the index is valid
    if (index >= 1 && index <= products.length) {
        const product = products[index - 1];
        return `--- ${product.name} Details ---\n\n${product.description}`;
    } else {
        return "Invalid product index.";
    }
};

const reportIssue = (userMessage) => {
    if (!userData.name) {
        userData.name = userMessage;
        return "Thanks for providing your name. Please provide your email address:";
    } else if (!userData.email) {
        userData.email = userMessage;
        return "Thanks for providing your email address. Please describe the issue you're experiencing:";
    } else if (!userData.issue) {
        userData.issue = userMessage;
        isReportingIssue = false; // Issue reporting completed
        return "Issue Submitted. Thank you for reporting!";
    }
};


const showDefaultMessage = () => {
    return `
     Welcome to Vinayan India 

         --- All ---
        1 - See our Products
        2 - Report Issue
        3 - Talk to our sales team
    `
}


const showHelpDesk = () => {
    return `
     Thanks for contacting Vinayayan India Help Desk

        You can contact this number 
        for any help regarding our products: 8527988811

    `
}


const footer = `

  Created With ❤️ by Vinayan India (vinayan.net)

`


router.post('/', async function (req, res, next) {
    const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
    const userMessage = req.body.Body.trim();

    const waId = req.body.From;
    // Get or create session for the user based on WhatsApp ID (waId)
    req.session.waId = waId;

    try {
        let user = await User.findOne({ waId: req.body.From });
        if (!user) {
            user = new User({ waId: req.body.From });
        }

        user.messages.push({
            smsMessageSid: req.body.SmsMessageSid,
            numMedia: req.body.NumMedia,
            profileName: req.body.ProfileName,
            smsSid: req.body.SmsSid,
            smsStatus: req.body.SmsStatus,
            body: req.body.Body,
            to: req.body.To,
            numSegments: req.body.NumSegments,
            referralNumMedia: req.body.ReferralNumMedia,
            messageSid: req.body.MessageSid,
            accountSid: req.body.AccountSid,
            from: req.body.From,
            apiVersion: req.body.ApiVersion,
        });


        // Retrieve the user's last message from the database
        const lastMessage = user.messages[user.messages.length - 2];


        let response = null;


        if (isViewingProducts) {
            const index = parseInt(userMessage);
            response = getProductDetails(index);
            isViewingProducts = false;
        } else if (isReportingIssue) {
            response = reportIssue(userMessage);
        } else {
            switch (userMessage.toLowerCase()) {
                case "1":
                    response = showProducts();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    userData = {};
                    isReportingIssue = true;
                    response = "Please provide your name to report the issue:";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    response = showHelpDesk();
                    break;
                default:
                    response = showDefaultMessage();
            }
        }

         // Save response message to database
        user.messages.push({
            body: response,
            from: 'Your Application' // Assuming this is the identifier for the bot
        });

        // Save user data to database
        await user.save();

        twiml.message(response + '\n' + footer);
        res.status(200).send(twiml.toString());

    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
    

});




module.exports = router;
```

I want to create a session for every user so that it first checks the whatsapp Id for every user before applying so that it reply to the user it is conversing to.